# How to use multi regex pattern in psql?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, psql

trying found out relation name in public schema that contain string "main" and "parted".

So far I have tried.

```
\dt public.(*main* | *parted*)
-- ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced
```

I also tried the following queries:

```
SELECT
    regexp_match('parted1 new main', '(main|parted\S+)');

SELECT
    regexp_matches('main new parted1', '(main|parted\S+)');

SELECT
    regexp_substr ('main new parted1', '(main|parted\S+)');

SELECT
    regexp_substr ('main new parted1', '(main|parted\S+)');
```

I expect a pattern that will match substring that have pattern "main" or "parted\S+".

In psql manual:

> All regular expression special characters work as specified in Section
> 9.7.3, except for . which is taken as a separator as mentioned above, * which is translated to the regular-expression notation .*, ? which is translated to ., and $ which is matched literally.
> From the quote so it's doable?

Comment: `\dt public.(*main*|*parted*)` (without the spaces!) works for me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. Problem solved. we can also  `\dtv public.(*main*|*parted*|*stat*)`